# How to Upgrade Eclipse that plugin with Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin

I have an question about my Eclipse.
It is JUNO version and it is plugin with SDK and ADT.
So I want to update to higher version, because I cannot estimate the word or method that will appear next.
Example:  System.out   (but i want When I type System and then Type dot to show what next is).
Thank you!

Comment: FYI it is the IDE that 'estimates' the word or the method and not you.Switch to Android Studio and your'estimate' issue will be solved,as the support for Eclipse ADT has shutdown

Comment: According Android developpers doc : "If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates."  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Because I cannot estimate the next word or the method that is why I want to use the Eclipse that can estimate for me...

Comment: Thank you all. I will use Android Studio asap.